# Realm fine grain notifications Swift 3 syntax

Tags: swift, realm

I think this should be a pretty simple, but I can't figure it out because I don't have a solid grasp on generics or enums with arguments.

Previously I had an extension to UITableView for handling fine grain notifications that looked like this

```
func updateTableWithChanges<AnyType>(changes:RealmCollectionChange<Results<AnyType>>) {
    switch changes {
    case .Initial:
        self.reloadData()
    case .Update(let results, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
        beginUpdates()
        // DO STUFF
        endUpdates()
    case .Error(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Since migrating to Swift 3 the syntax has changed and I can't figure out what is supposed to go in the case's parenthesis. The new syntax is

```
switch changes {
    case .initial(T):
        break
    case .update(T, deletions: [Int], insertions: [Int], modifications: [Int]):
        break
    case .error(Error):
        break
    }
```

What are the arguments with the enum cases (especially T), and how do I access them now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently how it has to be done now. I dug through the Swift 3 documentation and was able to sort it out.

```
switch changes {
    case .initial(_):
        reloadData()
    case let .update(_, deletions, insertions, modifications):
        beginUpdates()
        // DO STUFF
        endUpdates()
    case let .error(error):
        print(error)
}
```

Comment: If you're not using the associated values in an enum case, you should still be able to leave out the parentheses in Swift 3 (`case .initial:`, `case .update`, etc).